# Finding the value of one-sided limits and greatest integer function.

Tags: calculus, limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> $$
> \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{a}{x} \left\lfloor\frac{x}{b} \right\rfloor
> $$

The $\lfloor \rfloor$ stands for the greatest integer function.

I have calculated and the left-hand limit is coming as (ab). But, I have doubt in the right-hand limit. I did this problem by sandwich-theorem. Can, anyone help me to find the right-hand limit correctly?

Comment: The more common name for the $\lfloor x \rfloor$ function is the "floor" function.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Assuming $b \ne 0$,

$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{a}{x} \left\lfloor\frac{x}{b} \right\rfloor
= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{a}{bx} \left\lfloor \frac{bx}{b}\right\rfloor
= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{a}{b} \left( \frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{x}\right)
= \frac{a}{b} \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{x}
$$

For $x$ near $0$, $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is just $0$ on the right and $-1$ on the left.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that
$a > 0$
and $b > 0$.

If $0 < x < b$,
$\lfloor \frac{x}{b} \rfloor
= 0$.

Therefore,
for
$0 < x < b$,
$\frac{a}{x}\lfloor \frac{x}{b} \rfloor
= 0$.

Therefore,
$\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{a}{x}\lfloor \frac{x}{b} \rfloor
= 0$.

The expression is not defined at $x = 0$.

If $0 > x > -b$,
$\lfloor \frac{x}{b} \rfloor
= -1$.

Therefore,
for
$0 > x > -b$,
$\frac{a}{x}\lfloor \frac{x}{b} \rfloor
= -\frac{a}{x}$.

This is not defined
as $x \to 0^{-}$.